# Other: Different range into Master Sheet from Child Sheets

Tags: python, google-apps-script

There is a **Master** worksheet, which needs to be populated by *more than 75* **child** sheets with different values.

**EDIT:**
The situation has changed slightly.

```
  'AGENTS'
  Agent Name  Sheet ID
1 Tom         Link to Tom's sheet
2 John        Link to John's sheet
3 Mary        Link to Mary's sheet
etc.
```

links to:

```
'MASTER SHEET'
        A                    C                       D
    Agent Name  Value 1 from Agent's Sheet Value 2 from Agent's Sheet
1                           D46                     D53
2                           D46                     D53
3                           D46                     D53
```

Also this is based on 1 cell which refers to the week no.
So if the cell F11 on the Master is '39' it would pull the data from the agent sheets from that particular week.

I have made a *feeble* attempt to alter the code to this:

```
var agentNames = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('AGENTS').getRange('A2:A35').getValues();//these are the agent names
var agentID = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('AGENTS').getRange('B2:B35').getValues();//here are their sheets
var agentSheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(agentSheets[i][0]);
var array1 = [];
var array2 = [];
var array3 = [];
var masterSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('MASTER');
var sheetName =   SpreadsheetApp.openById('B2') + 'F2' + (masterSheet.getRange('F11').getValue());
var temp;

for (var i = 0; i < numAgents; i++) {
temp = SpreadsheetApp.openById(agentSheets[i][1]).getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange('D46:D53').getValues();
array1.push([agents[i][0]]);
array2.push([temp[0][0]]);
array3.push([temp[7][0]]);
    }

masterSheet.getRange(2, 1, numAgents, 1).setValues(array1);//Agent names
masterSheet.getRange(2, 3, numAgents, 2).setValues(array2);
masterSheet.getRange(2, 4, numAgents, 2).setValues(array3);

 }
```

Would JavaScript be the next best solution for this issue? The loading times seem to be very long when the script runs for 75 or more sheets. Any suggestion or advice is welcome on how to proceed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

7My fairly simple advice would be, wherever possible, try to do your gets and sets in batches, and not within loops. So it is generally better to construct a Javascript array, and set it in one go. Below is my guess at some code:

```
function consolidate() {
  var agents = [['John', 'sheet_id'],
                ['Mary', 'sheet_id'],
                ['Tom', 'sheet_id']];
  var numAgents = agents.length;
  var array1 = [];
  var array2 = [];
  var array3 = [];
  var array4 = [];
  var masterSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('MASTER');
  var sheetName = 'WEEK ' + (masterSheet.getRange('A1').getValue());
  var temp;

  for (var i = 0; i < numAgents; i++) {
    temp = SpreadsheetApp.openById(agents[i][1]).getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange('D41:D49').getValues();
    array1.push([agents[i][0]]);
    array2.push([temp[4][0], temp[0][0]]);
    array3.push([temp[7][0], temp[8][0]]);
    array4.push([temp[6][0]]);
  }

  masterSheet.getRange(2, 1, numAgents, 1).setValues(array1);
  masterSheet.getRange(2, 4, numAgents, 2).setValues(array2);
  masterSheet.getRange(2, 9, numAgents, 2).setValues(array3);
  masterSheet.getRange(2, 14, numAgents, 1).setValues(array4);
}
```

Comment: This is a very good code to use if the range was strictly between D41:D49, I just tried your code out, however in columns D I and J an'undefined' message appeared. Does that mean it would be advisable to change the range on the Master sheet?

Comment: I'm sorry, I got the array indices the wrong way around, try the edited code. Regarding "if the range was strictly between D41:D49", you will need to elaborate your original question a bit.

Comment: Is there a possibility to add an IF.. ELSE.. NEXT statement to ensure that if the agent name is not found for that particular week the script would continue? (PS Thank you for the edit!)